# PHP, convert many different date formats into day-month-year

Tags: php, date-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert php date formats to GMT and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454779/how-to-convert-php-date-formats-to-gmt-and-vice-versa)

In PHP, I have a string date like this:

```
May 21, 2012 07:23:15 GMT
```

or this

```
21 May 2012 07:23:15 GMT
```

I need to convert both the strings into something like this: `21-05-2012`. (day-month-year)

Can PHP correctly parse both these strings into a day-month-year format?

Comment: And how, exactly, do you get the string in the first place?

Comment: isnt that an obvious question... read the first line of my question

Comment: No, you simply state that you 'get a string such as this.' Where is it from, do you create it? What are you using? Can you format it at the point of creation rather than tidying it up afterwards?

Comment: I get it as a string from a page.. using scraping.. does that help?

Comment: It does, the more information you can provide leads to better, or at least more appropriate, solutions for your problem, and should better fit the context of that problem.

Comment: too late with your downvotes and closes..lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This -

```
 $your_string = "21 May 2012 07:23:15 GMT";
 $dd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($your_string));
 echo $dd;
```

Comment: Cool :) hope its going to be an expected answer now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the DateTime class?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
$date = new DateTime("May 21, 2012 07:23:15 GMT");
print $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: no..interesting solution..I will try it

Comment: Added the date_default_timezone_set(), you may need that.

Comment: This works the same way as `strtotime()` (see the manual page for ["Compound Formats"](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) for details).

Comment: @Radu In most ways it does but it gives an object oriented approach to the problem, some will prefer that.

Comment: @h00ligan, sure, just pointing out the fact that it uses the same logic, so as not to expect anything different.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) for this. Alternatively, if you know what format to expect, you can use [`strptime()`](http://php.net/strptime) to parse it, which would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str_date = "May 21, 2012 07:23:15 GMT";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d, Y H:i:s O', $str_date);
echo  $date->format('d-m-Y');
```