# php new dateTime and gmdate

Tags: php

How would I convert the following so that it uses the [datetime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)?:

```
array(
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date),
    'post_date_gmt' => gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date),
);
```

Eg this part is easy but how about the gmdate?

```
$oDate = new DateTime($date);
array(
    'post_date' => $oDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_date_gmt' => gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date),
);
```

Comment: You just pass the `DateTimeZone` instance as 2nd parameter to `DateTime`. `$date = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('GMT'));`

Comment: For a full explanation , take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454779/how-to-convert-php-date-formats-to-gmt-and-vice-versa

Comment: @OfirBaruch thats perfect, I will close/delete this question

Comment: Lol I have to vote to close my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you need two object one for `GMT`.

```
$oDate = new DateTime($date);
$gmDate = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('GMT'));

array(
   'post_date'     => $oDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
   'post_date_gmt' => $gmDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$oDate->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$oDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Don't forget that after doing so he would like to get back to the standard timezone.