# Converting Unix time to GMT datetime with php

Tags: php, unix, datetime, time, instagram

I use Instagram API and there is one important field there, created_time. And those are in Unix timestamp format. I convert it to datetime with date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$insta_date); (PHP) And it gives me normal datetime with GMT+0. But i want it with GMT+3. Is there any shortest way to get GMT+N datetime from Unix timestamp?

Comment: set your date locale? http://lu1.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Thanks bwoebi. :) I thought time() is only in GMT+0 and could not b formatted to other timezones. But it was not so. It worked with date_default_timezone_set("Zone/City");.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454779/how-to-convert-php-date-formats-to-gmt-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the time to different timezone. The PHP function is:

```
date_default_timezone_set()
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) to get Greenwich Mean Time, and then add offset:

```
$offset = 3*60*60;    // +3 hours
gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $insta_date+$offset)
```

You can also use [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format a local time/date, if [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) is correct.