# Converting client side time to UTC on the server for storage

Tags: php, javascript, timezone

This may be a duplicate but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I want to store dates given by the client in UTC. I have a javascript [library](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) that detects the client's timezone and I'm sending the timezone name (e.g. America/Halifax) to the server with the rest of the form data.

I've been searching now for the php functions that I can use to take the date entered and the timezone and convert it to UTC.

I think `gmdate` is the correct function but how do I use the date entered and the timezone with `gmdate`?

Comment: I found the answer with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454779/how-to-convert-php-date-formats-to-gmt-and-vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting date_default_timezone_set('America/Halifax') at the top of your script.

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: What if the client using the application is in Europe? I want to store the date in UTC, but the users could be any where in the world. I was using 'America/Halifax' as an example.

Comment: @John - then you pass that time zone in as a variable