# Convert a String with GMT to DateTime Format - php

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, payment-gateway, gmt

I face this problem to integrate bKash Online Payment Gateway API. 
The Documentation is here - https://developer.bka.sh/docs/create-payment-1.

In 'Create Payment' section bKash return *paymentCreateTime* string as following format.

```
2020-01-07T11:55:34:438 GMT+0600
```

How can I convert it to `2020-01-07 11:55:34` to save in MySQL?

I find a solution like following way.

```
$input     = "2020-01-07T11:55:34:438 GMT+0600"                   // "2020-01-07T11:55:34:438 GMT+0600"
$timestamp = substr($input,0,19);                                 // "2020-01-07T11:55:34"
$mysql     = date_format(date_create($timestamp),'Y-m-d H:i:s');  // "2020-01-07 11:55:34"
```

But I need a solution without `substr()` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert php date formats to GMT and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454779/how-to-convert-php-date-formats-to-gmt-and-vice-versa)

Comment: use Carbon::parse()->format(Y-m-d H:i:s);

Comment: @Raymond - The following link is not like a solution to convert '2020-01-07T11:55:34:438 GMT+0600' to date-time format. Need a specified code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `createFromFormat()` to directly parse your string.

Importantly, you'll need to escape `T` and `GMT`.

Everything else in https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
$input = '2020-01-07T11:55:34:438 GMT+0600';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\Th:i:s:u \G\M\TO', $input);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

This will cleanly deliver an object that you can format however you like.

Here is a [demonstration](https://3v4l.org/9rT0c):

```
$date = new DateTime("now");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s:u \G\M\TO');

echo "\n---\n";

$input = '2020-01-07T11:55:34:438 GMT+0600';
echo $input;

echo "\n---\n";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\Th:i:s:u \G\M\TO', $input);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');

echo "\n===\n";

var_dump($date);
```

Demonstration Output:

```
2020-01-07T10:12:53:000245 GMT+0100
---
2020-01-07T11:55:34:438 GMT+0600
---
2020-01-07 11:55:34
===
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-01-07 11:55:34.438000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+06:00"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
$mysql1 = date_format(date_create(strtotime($input)),'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

it will print `2020-01-07 09:17:23`

Comment: Here, if I set 
$input = "2020-01-07T11:55:34:438 GMT+0600";
Then,
strtotime($input)                              // false
date_create(strtotime($input))        // date: 2020-01-07 14:23:31.486348 Asia/Dhaka (+06:00) 

That is the present time, not the $input variable time.

Comment: Are we accommodating 3 digits of microseconds or 6 digits?

Comment: updated the code. just set date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka"); at top of your code . it will give you current time

Comment: >>> $input
=> "2020-01-07T11:55:34:438 GMT+0600"
>>> date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
=> true
>>> $mysql1 = date_format(date_create(strtotime($input)),'Y-m-d H:i:s');
=> "2020-01-07 15:55:51"
Sorry. This is not perfect result.

Comment: then what you need ?